# Ruby Rack: startup and teardown operations (Tokyo Cabinet connection)

Tags: ruby, connection, sinatra, rack, tokyo-cabinet

I have built a pretty simple REST service in Sinatra, on Rack. It's backed by 3 Tokyo Cabinet/Table datastores, which have connections that need to be opened and closed. I have two model classes written in straight Ruby that currently simply connect, get or put what they need, and then disconnect. Obviously, this isn't going to work long-term.

I also have some Rack middleware like Warden that rely on these model classes.

What's the best way to manage opening and closing the connections? Rack doesn't provide startup/shutdown hooks as I'm aware. I thought about inserting a piece of middleware that provides reference to the TC/TT object in env, but then I'd have to pipe that through Sinatra to the models, which doesn't seem efficient either; and that would only get be a per-request connection to TC. I'd imagine that per-server-instance-lifecycle would be a more appropriate lifespan.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have other Rack middleware that depend on these connections (by way of a dependence on your model classes), then I wouldn't put the connection logic in Sinatra -- what happens if you rip out Sinatra and put in another endpoint?

Since you *want* connection-per-application rather than connection-per-request, you could easily write a middleware that initialized and cleaned up connections (sort of the Guard Idiom as applied to Rack) and install it ahead of any other middleware that need the connections.

```
class TokyoCabinetConnectionManagerMiddleware
  class <<self
    attr_accessor :connection
  end

  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    open_connection_if_necessary!
    @app.call(env)
  end

  protected

  def open_connection_if_necessary!
    self.class.connection ||= begin
      ... initialize the connection ..
      add_finalizer_hook!
    end
  end

  def add_finalizer_hook!
    at_exit do
      begin
        TokyoCabinetConnectionManagerMiddleware.connection.close!
      rescue WhateverTokyoCabinetCanRaise => e
        puts "Error closing Tokyo Cabinet connection. You might have to clean up manually."
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If you later decide you want connection-per-thread or connection-per-request, you can change this middleware to put the connection in the `env Hash`, but you'll need to change your models as well. Perhaps this middleware could set a `connection` variable in each model class instead of storing it internally? In that case, you might want to do more checking about the state of the connection in the `at_exit` hook because another thread/request might have closed it.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using Sinatra's `configure` blocks to set up your connections?

```
configure do
  Connection.initialize_for_development
end

configure :production do
  Connection.initialize_for_production
end
```

That's a pretty common idiom while using things like DataMapper with Sinatra

Check out the "Configuration" section at http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro

Comment: you sir win the prize. This is the only answer out of several SO posts that worked!